# Executing Powershell script from Websocket svia c# to stop/start website

Tags: c#, powershell, iis, websocket

We have a need to remotely start/stop IIS websites and app pools, so we can remotely deploy a website.
I have a Websocket app that starts a PowerShell script to complete these activities.  I built Powershell scripts to complete that tasks and they work perfectly in the Powershell prompt.  However, when I try to run these scripts from the websocket, the scripts run (I have Write-Outputs in the scripts), but nothing happens the site and pool do not change.  I don't see anything that says it failed, either.  I would appreciate any help that can be given.

Below is an excerpt from the code:

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    string scriptContent = string.Empty;
    string pathToReadScriptFile = string.Empty;
    // add a script that creates a new instance of an object from the caller's namespace
    if (r.StartStop.ToLower() == "stop")
    {
        pathToReadScriptFile = Path.Combine(scriptsPath, "StopPoolAndSite.ps1");
    }
    else
    {
        pathToReadScriptFile = Path.Combine(scriptsPath, "StartPoolAndSite.ps1");
    }

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToReadScriptFile))
    {
        scriptContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }

    ps.AddScript(scriptContent);
    ps.AddParameter("siteName", r.SiteName);
    ps.AddParameter("poolName", r.PoolName);

    // invoke execution on the pipeline (collecting output)
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = ps.Invoke();

    // loop through each output object item
    foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
    {
        if (outputItem != null)
        {
            await SendMessageToAllAsync($"{outputItem.ToString()}");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is one of the powershell script code:

```
Param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
 [string]$siteName ,
 [string]$poolName
     )

if (-Not $poolName)
{
$poolName = $siteName
Write-Output "PoolName not supplied.  Using $siteName as default. "
} 

Import-Module WebAdministration
Write-Output "Preparing to Start AppPool: $poolName"
Write-Output "(OutPut)Preparing to Start AppPool: $poolName"
Start-WebAppPool  $poolName 

Write-Output "Preparing to Start Site: $siteName"
Start-WebSite  $siteName 
Get-WebSite  $siteName
```

Comment: I just added code to pull the errors from the executing script.  What I found was that the Web-Administration "import" failed, because the feature is not .net Core, which is the framework used by this app.  Any one know of any work arounds?

Comment: Hi Could you get it work from local vs IIS Express? If so, then it could be a permission issue. Try to set  your authentication for example IUSR to use application pool identity and set application pool identity to local system. MS Process monitor could also be used to troubleshooting Security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i would suggest not to reinvent the wheel there is a project for that check these out :

- https://github.com/microsoft/iis.administration
- https://manage.iis.net/get

Comment: Eldar, thanks for the reply.  I have read thru the docs and this seems to be what we are wanting to do, with the possible exception of needing to assign security to a website by a specific user/group, so different dev's can  only shut off the site for which they are responsible.  I don't see that option.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you can use windows and  token based authentication and you can provide role based authorization see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/IIS-Administration/configuration/appsettings.json#security)